# Should the “for” attribute always come first in an HTML <label> tag for readability?

Tags: html

In an HTML `<label>` tag, say there are some custom attributes in the tag and one or more of them alphabetically come before the `for` attribute. Should the `for` attribute come first for good style/readability, or does this not matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the HTML attributes is irrelevant.

You can try and be consistent for readability, but the DOM parser does not care and once parsed, they do not have any specific order (though in practice they *may* appear in the order they were assigned).

Personally I would place the `for` attribute first as other developers looking at your HTML will look for it (and want to see it first).

Answer (score 2):

Up to you/your team, really.

I personally prefer `for` to always come first, as it’s the thing I’m most likely to want to check for correctness, but if you’ve got custom attributes I guess they might be equally as important.